# Storing User Input into a Variable

Tags: java

User input isn't updating the corresponding variable. 
I am trying to update the Dexterity variable when a user inputs a number when prompted.

I have created a setDex method that should take the user input amount and update it when added to the getDex method. The getDex method should be retrieving the current value of the variable.

```
public class SetAttributes {


    double Dexterity;
    double Strength;
    double Intelligence;
    double Stamina;
    double SkillPoints = 50;



    public SetAttributes() {
        this.setDex(0);
        this.setStr(0);
        this.setInt(0);
        this.setSta(0);
        this.setSkillPoints(50);
    }

    public double getSP(){
        return SkillPoints;

    }
    public double getDex() {
        return Dexterity;
    }

    public double getStr(){
        return Strength;
    }

    public double getInt(){
        return Intelligence;
    }

    public double getSta(){
        return Stamina;
    }




    public void setDex(double dexterity) {
        this.Dexterity = Dexterity;
    }
    public void setStr(double strength){
        this.Strength = Strength;
    }
    public void setInt(double intelligence){
        this.Intelligence = Intelligence;
    }
    public void setSta(double stamina){
        this.Stamina = Stamina;
    }
    public void setSkillPoints(double skillPoints) {this.SkillPoints = SkillPoints;};
}




public final class PointSpender {




    public static void Spend(){

        SetAttributes Attribute = new SetAttributes();


        Scanner SkillChoice = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What skill do you want to increase? Dex, Str, Sta, or Int?");



        switch(SkillChoice.nextLine().charAt(0)){
            case 'd':
                System.out.println("How many points towards Dexterity?");
                System.out.println("Your current Dexterity is " + Attribute.Dexterity);

          double amount = SkillChoice.nextDouble();



                Attribute.setDex(amount + Attribute.getDex());
              System.out.println(Attribute.Dexterity);
```

Comment: You should really read up on naming conventions. Now it looks like your entire code is riddled with nothing but static method calls.

Answer (score 1):

All of your setter methods follow the same problem (this is why you should follow conventions like variables being `camelCase`), so let's pick any of them.

```java
public void setSta(double stamina){
    this.Stamina = Stamina;
}
```

As you can see you set the class level variable `Stamina` equal to the variable `Stamina`. The method parameter is called `stamina`. So what you're setting `this.Stamina` to is itself.

Answer (score 0):

In java variables are case sensitive

```
this.Dexterity = Dexterity;
```

should be

```
this.Dexterity = dexterity;
```

else  they are referring to the same variable

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setDex(double dexterity) {
    this.Dexterity = Dexterity;
}
```

First of all, `this.Dexterity = Dexterity;` must be `this.Dexterity = dexterity;` because `dexterity` is the variable that need to be assigned to `Dexterity`. 
And when you use `this.Dexterity = Dexterity;`, actually you are assigning the value of  `Dexterity` to `Dexterity` which is actually meaningless.

All setter methods you have written, have same problem.

And finally try to maintain naming convention.